Shared library constructor not being executed upon dlopen()
Given module.c:
__attribute__((constructor)) int init_module() {
  printf("Module init\n");
  return 0;
}

__attribute__((destructor)) int deinit_module() {
  printf("Module deinit\n");
  return 0;
}

Compiled with gcc -shared -fPIC -o module_A.so module.c.
Calling dlopen() on this so-file, doesn't run the constructor.

The name of the init_module() function is the culprit. Change it to anything else, such as library_init() or even further from anything that potentially sounds like a system-function: my_library_init().
It seems that https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html is an existing function, so probably the linker doesn't allow you to accidentally call that upon loading the library, simply because you share the symbol name.

TO be safe always use MYMODULENAME_function_name

I agree with @0___________ that proper naming practice is to put the name first as a prefix. You can have a module.h and module.c, in which all public functions should start with the prefix module_ and all public macros or constants etc should start with MODULE_. This makes the project much more maintainable overall, as one can easily tell which code module a particular function belongs to.
